# How to maintain state of upload option parallelly in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making an `API` request which returns me with `upload_option`, I'm storing these `options` in `state` `upload_option`.
The upload option is an array of strings.

upload_option = ["tracks", "Video", "Files"]

```
this.state.upload_option.map(entry => {
    <div>
      <label for='..'>{option}</label>
      <input type='file'/>
    </div>
```

So the above code works fine with UI but when it comes to the `state`, I need to maintain 3 different `states` parallelly so I can display the file uploaded.

Once I upload the file in option_1 and after that, if I upload the file in option_2, option_1 state resets. Is there any other way to maintain the state ?

Comment: I don't know the type of your upload_option ? It seems that it is an array and you put options to the array . maybe you should add more detail about your action.

Comment: option_1 contains what exactly?

Comment: updated the question